# Python Tornado: параметры URL

Tags: python, tornado

Добрый день.

Пишу небольшой сервер на Python Tornado, не могу понять, как получить параметры из URL такого вида:

```
localhost/search/XYZ?from=2017-03-07
```

здесь XYZ это не название параметра, а его значение. Как получить from, понятно, в handler'е пишем

```
from = self.get_argument("from")
```

как получить значение XYZ? Сама структура URL задана жёстко, и всегда имеет указанный вид. Роутинг имеет вид

```
application = tornado.web.Application([    
    (r"/search/", SearchHandler),
])
```

в самом handler'е написано что-то вроде

```
class SearchHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
application = tornado.web.Application([    
    (r"/search/(\w+)", SearchHandler),
])

class SearchHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, path_param):
        ...
```

Comment: да, то, что требовалось, спасибо